# Use of fluent interfaces to validate objects using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, fluent

Im currently doing a side project to validate objects using java 8.

Currently I have this:

- An interface that is essencially a rewrite of the java 8 predicate interface:

[image]

Then, I created the implementation of that same interface:

[image]

And then this class is the result of my validation

[image]

The concrete object validation can be found here:

```
public class ConcreteValidator implements EmployeeValidator {
  @Override
  public void validate(Employee employee) throws EmployeeException {

    ValidatorUtil.notNullString.and(ValidatorUtil.notEmptyString)
        .and(ValidatorUtil.stringBetween(1, 100)).test(employee.getFirstName())
        .getFieldNameIfInvalid(" Please specify valid firstname ").orElse("");

    ValidatorUtil.notNullString.and(ValidatorUtil.notEmptyString)
        .and(ValidatorUtil.stringBetween(1, 100)).test(employee.getLastName())
        .getFieldNameIfInvalid(" Please specify valid lastname ").orElse("");

    ValidatorUtil.notNullString.and(ValidatorUtil.notEmptyString)
        .and(ValidatorUtil.stringBetween(3, 100)).test(employee.getEmail())
        .getFieldNameIfInvalid(" Please specify valid email ").orElse("");

    ValidatorUtil.notNullInteger.and(ValidatorUtil.greaterThanZero)
        .and(ValidatorUtil.integerBetween(18, 60)).test(employee.getAge())
        .getFieldNameIfInvalid(" Please specify valid age ").orElse("");
  }
}
```

This works fine but what I want to do now is to limit the user to use the notNull verification first, and only after that validation all the methods like notEmpty or greaterThanZero will be available.

I searched for fluent interfaces but don't know if it is the correct way to do it (want to do something like this: https://code-held.com/2019/04/29/robust-builder-pattern/)

To summarise, I want to force the developer to validate if the object is null first and all the other methods go next, something like the chaining of the Stream API in java-8.Here is my customValidations.

[image]

Comment: You should copy the code rather than putting images.

Comment: If it is a requirement that they always validate for non-null, you could simply make that automatic. The validator could check for non-null before applying any other validations, and the client would not have to specify the non-null check. Also, please enter code as text, not images.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not with how you do your methods: `<K> GenericValidation<K> from(Predicate<K> predicate)`.

By doing so, you tell the developer he can pass any Java expressions: you can't validate the content of the expression at runtime, unlike you want to play with bytecode - which you don't.

You need to enforce this using the compiler, for example:

```
GenericValidation<K> fromNonNull(Predicate<K> predicate) {
  return from(val -> val != null && predicate.test(val));
}
```

Or using types as shown below:

```
validateThat(employee.getFirstName()) // return a StringValidator1
  .isNotNull() // return a StringValidator2
  .isNotEmpty()
  .hasLengthBetween(1, 100)
  ;
```

`StringValidator1` only have `isNotNull()` and return `StringValidator2`.

That's how you would enforce the `isNotNull()` check with the compiler: by returning another type providing more services than the default. Since `StringValidator1` does not have `isNotEmpty()`, then the compiler would generate a compilation error by trying to call it.

You may read [AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core) code for how they do their fluent interface. There are of course other source code being fluent (and I think the most important part of "fluent", is that the compiler and IDE **helps** you in validating what you are doing).